# print contents of file after ssh-initiated login session?

Tags: ssh

I want the contents of a file to be printed upon ssh login to a unix system, if that file exists. MOTD already prints as well as a banner set in `sshd_config`. I want to print another file also. How might I go about doing this. I am trying to us the rc file but have not got it working, can I set the contents of the file to a variable in environment and print it via rc, how would you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

You can use *ForceCommand* (a sshd configuration option)

> Forces the execution of the command specified by ForceCommand,
>   ignoring any command supplied by the client and ~/.ssh/rc if
>   present.  The command is invoked by using the user's login shell
>   with the -c option.  This applies to shell, command, or subsystem
>   execution.  It is most useful inside a Match block.  The command
>   originally supplied by the client is available in the
>   SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND environment variable.  Specifying a command
>   of ''internal-sftp'' will force the use of an in-process sftp
>   server that requires no support files when used with
>   ChrootDirectory.  The default is ``none''.

Just make it point to the wrapper script which will display your message, and then run the shell.

*Sample sshd_config (OpenSSH_7.2p2):*

```
Port 22
Protocol 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024

SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes

IgnoreRhosts yes
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
HostbasedAuthentication no

PermitEmptyPasswords no

ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes

AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

UsePAM yes

ForceCommand /usr/local/bin/ssh-wrapper
```

*/usr/local/bin/ssh-wrapper*

```
#!/bin/sh
[ -r "/etc/ssh_banner" ] && cat /etc/ssh_banner
CMD=${SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND:+-c $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND} 
exec $SHELL -l $CMD
```

That will display a message in /etc/ssh_banner, if this file is there.

Comment: Hmm tried `ForceCommand "/sbin/myscript.sh"` in the `sshd_config` but it appears to do nothing. Will investigate further thanks.

Comment: Have you restarted you _sshd_ (or sent it a SIGHUP), after you have made the change ?

Comment: I sure have. Using openssh if that matters.

Comment: Hmm, I also have OpenSSH:

     OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016

and it does indeed work just nice for me

Comment: Weird, I have the same openssh, would you mind sticking your config on pastebin?

Comment: I've updated answer to include my sshd config as well as the sample ForceCommand script, I've used.